# Log4Net in App object?

Tags: wpf, log4net

I am getting started with Logging in a WPF desktop app, using Log4Net as the logging component. Here is my question: In a simple desktop app, is there any reason not to instantiate my logger as a property ov the App class (App.xaml.cs), like this?

```
public partial class App : Application
{
        private static readonly ILog p_Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        public ILog Logger
        {
            get { return p_Logger; }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

That would allow me to invoke the logger

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One reason springs to mind: since the `App` class's static constructor is the first bit of your code that will run, you will be instantiating the `ILog` instance before you've configured log4net. Therefore, you `ILog` instance won't be usable. Generally, you would instead do something like this:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private static ILog log;

    static App()
    {
        XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(App));
    }
}
```

BTW, that `MethodBase` business really makes me cringe. Why not just use `typeof(App)`? You shouldn't be copy/pasting code without verifying it, anyway...and `typeof(App)` will work just fine with refactoring tools...

Answer (score 3):

A couple of cases **against** using one global instance. By using one logger per class you get:

- the benefit of logger hierarchies automatically following your class structure.
- lesser coupling (your classes no longer have a dependency on the App class).

Answer (score 2):

I did find a reason not to use a global logger in the App object. It works fine, but there is an advantage to getting a logger from within each class that will use it--It makes my log messages shorter and easier to write.

So I call GetLogger() in each class that will log, and I specify the name to be used for the logger. For example, in my OpenFile method, I can get a logger like this:

```
// Get logger
var logger = LogManager.GetLogger("OpenFile");
```

That relieves me of entering the class name in every error message I write. I still configure log4net in the App() constructor, since that only needs to be done once. That gives me a log message that looks like this:

```
2010-03-29 15:51:41,951 OpenFile [DEBUG]- Data file opened.
```

Kent's answer is still the accepted answer, but I figured I'd pass along what I had learned.